# Rails Query / where statement to find selected clients in checked pricerange?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been struggling with defining this query correctly for days, so I hope someone can help me out.

**I want so sort Clients by 3 parameters:**

- Category (category_id)
- Region (region_id)
- Pricerange1, Pricerange2, Pricerange3, Pricerange4, Pricerange5

All the priceranges are booleans, so the user choose multiple priceranges. Say $ and $$$ and $$$$$ at the same time.

My problem is that with my code right now, if you pick both $ and $$$ and $$$$$ at the same time, it tries to ONLY find clients where all 3 priceranges/conditions are met. So they have to be true at the same time. I want the search to find all clients if just ANY of the 3 priceranges are found.

So it should result in clients with for instance "$" being shown, but also clients with "$$$" and "$$$$$" - Without each necessarily having both priceranges.

I hope someone can help me. I think it's something with an & clause, but I'm lost

[Example in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT3Yz.jpg)

**Search.rb**

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
def results
    @results ||= find_results
end
private

def find_results
    results = Client.order(:name)
    results = results.where(visible: true)
    results = results.where(category_id: category_id) if category_id.present?
    results = results.where(region_id: region_id) if region_id.present?     
    results = results.where(pricerange1: pricerange1) if pricerange1.present?
    results = results.where(pricerange2: pricerange2) if pricerange2.present?
    results = results.where(pricerange3: pricerange3) if pricerange3.present?
    results = results.where(pricerange4: pricerange4) if pricerange4.present?
    results = results.where(pricerange5: pricerange5) if pricerange5.present?
    results
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Frame a conditions array as below and pass to your where condition.

```
conditions = []
results = Client.order(:name)
results = results.where(visible: true)
conditions << "category_id: #{category_id}" if category_id.present?
conditions << "region_id: #{region_id}" if region_id.present?
conditions << "pricerange1: #{pricerange1}" if pricerange1.present?
conditions << "pricerange2: #{pricerange2}" if pricerange2.present?
conditions << "pricerange3: #{pricerange3}" if pricerange3.present?
conditions << "pricerange4: #{pricerange4}" if pricerange4.present?
conditions << "pricerange5: #{pricerange5}" if pricerange5.present?
final_conditions = conditions.join(" and ")
results = results.where(final_conditions)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it when I get home. So this basically joins all the conditions in an array with 'and' so that any checked value is queried? Will a query for '$' + '$$$' + '$$$$$' like this, only show clients that have true checked in ALL of them? Or every client that just has one of these checked (at minimum)? :)

Comment: I get the following error-message when using the above code:
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': 3 and region_id: 2 and pricerange1: true)' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `clients` WHERE `clients`.`visible` = 1 AND (category_id: 3 and region_id: 2 and pricerange1: true)

It points to this code, where search.results is called: 
<% if @search.results.empty? %>
<div>Resultat</div>
<% end %>
I'm running MySQL2! I'll just update with some more code from the search.rb file

Comment: Remove the colon(:) from conditions and replace with "=" . something like this  - conditions << "category_id =  #{category_id}"

Comment: Edit: Your code works with "="! If I submit it with an = .. For instance conditions << "pricerange5 = #{pricerange5}" if pricerange5.present? In a query for $, $$$, and $$$$$ the problem remains though: It still only shows clients where all of these statements are true. I need it to work if just 1 (at minimum) is true. I tried adding "or" instead of "and" in that code, and that just gives me every available client. Can you help me pointing out where it might go wrong? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked. I hacked around with some of the code mentioned from Rajasekhar's comment.

```
private

def find_results
    results = Client.order(:name)
    results = results.where(visible: true)
    results = results.where(category_id: category_id) if category_id.present?
    results = results.where(region_id: region_id) if region_id.present?  

    conditions = []

    if pricerange1.present? and true
    conditions << "pricerange1 = #{pricerange1}"
    end
    if pricerange2.present? and true
    conditions << "pricerange2 = #{pricerange2}"
    end
    if pricerange3.present? and true
    conditions << "pricerange3 = #{pricerange3}"
    end
    if pricerange4.present? and true
    conditions << "pricerange4 = #{pricerange4}"
    end
    if pricerange5.present? and true
    conditions << "pricerange5 = #{pricerange5}" 
    end
    final_conditions = conditions.join(" or ")
    results = results.where(final_conditions)
end
```